# "Та-дам" или "Тадам"

Tags: орфография, грамматика, заимствования, части-речи

Как пишется правильно : "та-дам" или "тадам"(слова, которые употребляются, когда получилось показать фокус). И это слово является междометием?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этого слова нет в русских словарях, но оно есть в английских, так как это язык оригинала.

Ta-da или ta-dah - используется в качестве веселого междометия при объявлении, поклоне и т.д.

Следовательно, нужно писать через дефис и в русском.

Да, это междометие (interjection).

Источник:

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ta-dah